# How to change Android webview proxy authentication credentials without restarting the whole app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, proxy

I am using this method to setup proxy for the webview:

```
val proxyConfig = Builder().addProxyRule("$proxyHost:$proxyPort").addDirect().build()
ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, {}) {}
```

To authenticate i override `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()` in `WebViewClient` by entering the credentials using this line of code:

```
override fun onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view: WebView?,handler: HttpAuthHandler?, host: String?, realm: String?) {
  if(host == proxyHost)
    handler.proceed(proxyUsername, proxyPassword)
}
```

And it does work perfectly
The problem is when i change the credentials there are no any affect, i change the credentials using this code:

```
val webDB = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(webView.context)
webDB.clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword()
webDB.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(proxyHost, proxyRealm, proxyNewUsername, proxyNewPassword)
```

If i get the call the `webDB.getHttpAuthUsernamePassword(proxyHost, proxyRealm)` function it returns the new credentials but the proxy still logged in with the old credentials.

I also tried to clear the webview cache and cookies but still no change.

Note: `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` called only once in each app run.